# Android studio not showing all releavant xml for certain items

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rendering, emulation

developers! I am new to Android development. I am facing an issue that the emulator is not rendering images and titles from JSON objects. The emulator is showing a loading log so I don't think it is an issue of hardware. Also, I see that network is working to getting JSON data from the API site (Edamam API) when I run debug. I am using Retrofit for making a call of Edamam API. I fixed all the errors from LogCat and I don't see any errors except

> E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping
> failed for device_type=5, ret=-1

What do you do when you don't have an error in Logcat? Any suggestions? I have been working on this long time but not able to get the solutions.
What I tried...

- Uninstall the app from the emulator
- Changed adapter implementation code
- Changed emulator devices Added fields, methods, getter, and    setter
  on multiple classes
- Added Log.d too see where I am having a problem
- etc.. that I don't remember

[image: loading log showing but the recipe image is not rendering]

This is my code https://gist.github.com/Kijimu7/a8fb50a265618e6f0356c2e3277c90e3

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem.
I had a typo on my id to reference the layout file on CustomAdapter.java.
Also, I fixed the onResponse to

```
adapter.addAll(response.body().getHits());
```

to call Hits objects on MainActivity.java.